# Generic Database Connection C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

Im working on this application that will transfer data from a database another application. But I am trying to get the database functionality working.

I need to be able to connect any type of database (Oracle, SQL, etc...) to the app because my user base uses different databases.

I was following the tutorial on http://www.splinter.com.au/using-generic-database-providers-with-c/ and I'm having trouble connecting my test MySQL database to it.

Here is my sample code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string connection = "SERVER=localhost;UID=root;PASSWORD=toor";
    string provider = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient";

    using (DbConnection conn = (DbConnection)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(provider), connection))
    {
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "SHOW DATABASES";
        using(DbCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            comm.CommandText = sql;
            using(DbDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    string owner = reader.GetString(0);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", owner);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The error I'm getting is ArgumentNullException and I can see that in the debugger that conn is null. I'm not sure why it's not working though. I've used that connection string and provider in an app that uses the MySQL library. Could it be that my connection string needs to be changed? If so, what do I change it to?

Also, I don't want to add a Database to the connection string, that is chosen later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess `Type.GetType(provider)` returns `null` because you're specifying the type's Fullname

```
"MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
```

instead of its AssemblyQualifiedName

```
"MySql.Data.MySqlClient, MySql.Data"
```

Specifying a type name without an assembly name only works if the type is in the currently executing assembly or mscorlib.

If you are trying to load the assembly from the GAC you'll have to include the Version, Culture and PublicKeyToken parameters too, ie:

```
"MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
```

This depends on the version of the driver.

Comment: I tried that and I still get ArgumentNullException. But you are correct, the Type is null.

Comment: Did you place the MySql.Data.dll in the same folder as the executable? If you are trying to load it from the GAC you'll even have to be more specific, complete with Version, Culture and PublicKeyToken.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you had to do that. Does that mean I'll need to place dlls for every database the user might use? I suppose I could try to restrict it to just a few types.

Comment: @user yes, I'm afraid so. You could switch to ODBC, in which case the responsibility of finding the correct drivers shifts towards the system admin :) (ODBC is slower, and requires you to change all your queries, though)

Comment: It's still giving me that error, even with the .dll in the bin\Debug folder.

Comment: Could you use `Type.GetType(provider, true)` so you at least get an exception? It should contain a bit of information.

Comment: I got it working! I needed to use `"MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data"` as the provider. Thanks!

Comment: @user ahh I even copy pasted that in my last edit without noticing :) nice finding that, and good luck!

Comment: I was getting `Could not load type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' from assembly 'MySql.Data'.` as the exception. It looks like the assembly wasnt able to find the MySqlClient but it could find the MySqlClient.MySqlConnection